# Understanding Basic Storage Drive Structuring

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning

When using the application SPFDisk supply with a copy of Free DOS on a driver disk, included with my motherboard, I encountered a situation that didn't make much sense.  I was trying to zero every sector on the drive by manually using the "fill" feature in the app but couldn't get the app to accept the sector value shown on the last sector of the disk.  The values shown on the last sector were 60,800 cylinders, 254 heads, 63 sectors and 976,768,064 LBA sectors with a hex value in parentheses next to that quantity.  This is for a 500G drive.

When I jumped back to the beginning of the disk and tried entering in the LBA sector value when prompted for how many sectors to fill, it wouldn't accept any value that was remotely close and after many iterations, I finally came to the number it would accept, which was 4,194,303.  Can someone please explain the logic of why entering in the LBA sector value shown for the last sector of the disk, or some multiple, wouldn't be accepted and why the value of 4,194,303 was the largest number it would?

Comment: Depending on what you were looking at the sectors were reserved to recover bad sectors.

Comment: @Seth That also doesn't make much sense to me because 1) the value I was looking at is like a counter value and dynamically changes with the change of a button press to move forward or backward in sector value and 2) that would mean that 99.99% of the drive is reserved for bad sectors.  Will you please elaborate?

Comment: Perhaps `SPFDisk` does not work with larger drives? Or you don't have the appropriate disk driver loaded for your drive?

Comment: I will check the possibility with a missing or incorrect driver but also would like to note that this is a common occurrence across multiple PC's.

Comment: @DavidPostill To clarify your comment, I got the impression that what I've described is not due to a lack of my understanding and I should be able to enter in the LBA sector value indicated by the program at the end of the disk and that I'm not missing a fundamental concept on the structure of the disk, where there are 1 sector per side, 63 sectors per cylinder, 255 cylinders per head and 60,800 cylinders on the disk.  Is that correct?

Comment: The 63/255 CHS numbers are made up. (I wouldn't be surprised if a modern disk had *thousands* of sectors per track/cyl.) Disks haven't used CHS disk addressing for _decades;_ they just [fill in the fields with something](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/os2-disc-and-volume-size-limits.html) that kinda vaguely makes sense, even if it doesn't correspond to the physical layout. The only relevant number is LBA.

Answer (score 0):

4,194,303 is 0x3FFFFF in hexadecimal. Values between 0 .. 4,194,303 can be expressed with 22 bits, but any higher values will need the 23rd bit. It looks like your `SPFDisk` program has a limit of some sort at this point.

As a result, the `SPFdisk` program might be unable to handle disks larger than 2 GiB.

Historical note: the C/H/S geometry values became problematic at disks sized 504 MiB (528 MB). This was because although the maximum C/H/S geometry accepted by traditional BIOS is 1024/255/63 (resulting in a 7.8 GiB disk), the IDE hardware had a maximum geometry of 65536/16/255 (for 127.5 GiB). The original naive BIOS implementations resulted into the combination of these restrictions, resulting in a maximum geometry of 1024/16/63 (for 504 MiB). In July 1994, the IDE manufacturers developed the "geometry translation" technique that allowed the use of bigger disks.

But at the 7.8 GiB point, the C/H/S geometry stops working altogether, since the BIOS calls using this geometry have a fixed number of bits for the values (+ need to maintain compatibility with certain old DOS bugs). At that point, the way forward was to start disregarding the C/H/S geometry completely and moving to use the newer, LBA-style interface that had more bits available.

The problem with `SPFdisk` hits the exact range of sizes where it was still sort of possible to use the C/H/S geometries using BIOS-level geometry translation, and the LBA block numbers were not yet the preferred way to do things. The fact that `SPFdisk` even *displays* the C/H/S values indicates it's a rather old program that might not be able to handle the modern disks that would require LBA access to have a hope of handling their whole capacity.

[The link posted in the comments by @grawity](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/os2-disc-and-volume-size-limits.html) has a pretty good presentation of the various disk size limitations during the history of PCs.

Comment: That was a great explanation.  Thank you.